# preg_match "Text" "Mabye text" "Eight Numbers"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm new to preg and hope someone out there can help me.

I need to be able to match a text and then the next 8 consecutive digitals.

Eg. I got this string:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetuer number in iis 12345678 qui"
```

What I need to get out of this string is `number 12345678`.

I can only manage to get this out if it comes just after each other. For this I use this preg:

```
echo preg_match("/(number)\d{8}/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(number).*(\d{8})
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zI8hP1/1)**

[image]

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [32-38] `number`
2.  [46-54] `12345678`
```

You code would be:

```
$re = "/(number).*(\\d{8})/"; 
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetuer number in iis 12345678 qui"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```